# HTTP post with UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, http, uiwebview

I am quite new to Objective-C coding, learning at College at the moment so. Anyways, how do I perform a HTTP post with a UIWebview so that I can update the view when needed for a different flyer to put put there etc.

I may not even need to use HTTP post doing this, but my co-partner who is coding for Android insists I may need to!

Any help?

Comment: Hi you can use xui api to call web services or send post request to server using simple javascrit for more details how to call web services using javascript or in phonegap visit http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by flyer. But if you want a web page to appear in a UIWebView you don't need to use HTTP post, you just pass the url of a page to load to the UIWebView, or if you already have html content etc. you can load that content directly.

You can make HTTP requests directly but you probably don't need to. What exactly is it you want to display in the UIWebView?

Comment: I have sorted it now :) thanks for the reply, my mate was confusing me as he does android, so seems they do it a different way. The apps basically for a night club, so the flyer is basically an event for a specific night, sorted it now though (y)

Answer (score 0):

To make an HTTP Connection start by learning about `NSURLConnection` at [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

The first thing you're going to want to start with is making your `NSURL` objects then make your `NSURLRequest` with the parameters as well as the URL of your request. Then make a `NSURLConnection` and initiate the connection either asynchronously (preferred) or synchronously. If you want a synchronous (blocking) connection initialize it like so

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *responseHandler;
NSData *response = [myNSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myNSURLRequest, returningResponse:&responseHandler,error:&error];
```